# How to specify types on a Typescript object

Tags: typescript

Suppose I have a type and then I create an object with a value of this type e.g.

```
type MyType = {a: number, b: number, c: number}
const Defaults = {
    myDefault: {a: 5, b: 6, c: 7}
}
```

I want to be able to specify that `Defaults.myDefault` has type `MyType`. I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37503307/typescript-specify-type-in-object-declaration),
which tells me I can cast `myDefault` to `MyType`, but the problem is both

```
const Defaults = {myDefault: <MyType> {a: 5, b: 6, c: 7, d: 8}}
```

and

```
const Defaults = {myDefault: <MyType> {a: 5, b: 6}}
```

compile without error or even IDE warning, which kind of defeats the purpose. Basically what I want is the equivalent of

```
const Defaults : {myDefault: MyType} = {
    myDefault : {a: 5, b: 6, c: 7}
}
```

but being able to specify the `MyType` inside the object so that if I go on to add other defaults, I don't have to modify the code in two places:

```
// I don't want to go this way
export const Defaults : {myDefault: MyType, myOtherDefault: MyOtherType} = {
    myDefault : {a: 5, b: 6, c: 7}
    myOtherDefault : {d: 8, e: 9}
}
```

ON EDIT: Here's why I think this should be possible. If I make the defaults into functions, then it works; I can write:

```
const Defaults = {myDefault: () : MyType =>({a: 5, b: 6, c: 7})}
```

And now, if I either misspell something or leave off one of the properties, or add an extra one, I get a compile error. I guess I could just go this way, but why can't I just enforce a type on a non-functional property?

Answer (score 0):

What you're creating is an object in an object, so you need a type in a type:

```
type MyType = {a: number, b: number, c: number}

type DefaultType = {
  myDefault: MyType;
}

const Defaults: DefaultType = {
    myDefault : {a: 5, b: 6, c: 7}
}
```

Without being strict, there's little point in typing because you won't get type safety. However, you can extend the type by adding an optional `Record<string, unknown>`, which essentially means "...and other objects":

```
type DefaultType = {
  myDefault: MyType;
} & Record<string, unknown>

// then you can do
export const Defaults: DefaultType = {
    myDefault : {a: 5, b: 6, c: 7}
    myOtherDefault : {d: 8, e: 9}
  // another object here, and so on
}
```

Comment: I hear you, and that's maybe/probably the best I can do. But still, what I want is for the compiler to complain if I'm missing (or extra or misspelling...) a property on myDefault and myOtherDefault and anything else I want to default, but without having to explicitly have `DefaultType` because then every time I change it I have to change it in two places. Is that too much to ask? Maybe it is lol

Comment: That's kinda the whole point of type safety, though. Explicitly type out how it should be typed, so there's no room for ambiguity.

Comment: But I've already explicitly laid out MyType, which in reality is a lot bigger than this example, as are the others. Creating the `DefaultType` does nothing except force me to update the code in two places whenever there's a new type that I want to default. It may be impossible but I feel that I should be able to write something like `myDefault : MyType : {...}` inside of `Defaults` to specify the type right there.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `as` assertion to do what you want:

```
type MyType = {a: number, b: number, c: number}


const Defaults = {myDefault: {a: 5, b: 6} as MyType}
```

Comment: But then it doesn't complain about missing property `c`.

Comment: you have any idea why it's not complaining even when you write `const Defaults = {myDefault: {a: 5, b: 6} as Required<MyType>}
`?

Comment: I have no idea why, but on my machine it's doesn't complain. If you/anyone can make it complain, and also complain if I add `d: 8`, that would be great.

Comment: if I have  `abd`its complaining here that c is missing   `Property 'c' is missing in type '{ a: number; b: number; d: number; }' but required in type 'MyType'.(2352)` but it doesn't complain when i only have `ab` or `abcd` which is a bit annoying

Comment: Yeah I get the same thing, never tried that combination before. Kinda weird, I mean, I guess `abd` is arguably "more wrong" than either `ab` or `abcd` but come on lol...

Comment: @mrip I asked this one as question today. have a look here https://stackoverflow.com/q/71193992/9175097