# Typescript is not complaining about missing or too many object properties

Tags: typescript

Does anyone have an idea why Typescript is not complaining about the missing `c`?

```
type MyType = {a: number, b: number, c: number}


const Defaults = {myDefault: {a: 5, b: 6} as MyType}
```

If I have

```
const Defaults = {myDefault: {a: 5, b: 6, d: 9} as MyType}
```

it's complaining that `c` is a missing  property (not complaining d is unknown). But it's not complaining if I have just `ab` or `abcd`.

Adding `required` also changes nothing.

```
const Defaults = {myDefault: {a: 5, b: 6} as Required<MyType>}
```

Why could this be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html) in TypeScript allows you to

> convert to a more specific or less specific version of a type

If `type MyType = {a: number, b: number, c: number}` and `const Defaults = {myDefault: {a: 5, b: 6} as MyType}`, then for TypeScript `{a: 5, b: 6}` sufficiently overlapps with `MyType`. Its type is *contained* in `MyType`.

Now, consider `Defaults = {myDefault: {a: 5, b: 6, c:4, d: 3} as MyType}`, then this is also allowed. The object `{a: 5, b: 6, c:4, d: 3}` is more specific than `MyType` and we convert it to its less specific version, namely a type that only contains the properties `a, b` and `c`.

The type of `MyType` is *contained* in the type of the object `{a: 5, b: 6, c:4, d: 3}`.

For TypeScript the poperty `d:3` does not exist for `Defaults` since we have asserted `MyType`. Thus writing

```js
Defaults.myDefault.d
```

yields in

```
Property 'd' does not exist on type 'MyType'.
```

Of course we could access it at runtime since

> type assertions are removed at compile-time, there is no runtime checking associated with a type assertion

On the other hand, when writing

```js
const Defaults = {myDefault: {a: 5, b: 6, d: 9} as MyType}
```

the type of the object `{a: 5, b: 6, d: 9}` is neither contained in `MyType` nor is `MyType` contained in the type of `{a: 5, b: 6, d: 9}`.

This correctly yields to the error message

```
Conversion of type '{ a: number; b: number; d: number; }' to type 'MyType' may be a mistake because neither type sufficiently overlaps with the other.
```

But, we notice the following. The *intersection* of `MyType` and the type of `{ a: number; b: number; d: number; }` is `{a: number, b: number}`.

Writing

```js
const Defaults = {myDefault: {a: 5, b: 6,d:4} as MyType | {a:number, b:number}}
```

works. However, the property `c` can of course not be accessed.

**Edit:** In response to the comments. The `Required` construct in TypeScript does what you think it does, but with a minor difference. It turns all optional properties to required, which makes it the opposite of `Partial`. This has nothing to do with the type we are assigning to a given object, but whether or not the properties of that type are required or optional.

Consider the following.

```js
type MyType = {a: number, b: number, c?: number}

const Defaults = {myDefault: {a: 5, b:2} as MyType}

Defaults.myDefault.c
```

Checking the access to `c` yields

```js
(property) c?: number | undefined
```

However, asserting the type `MyType` as required

```js
type MyType = {a: number, b: number, c?: number}

const Defaults = {myDefault: {a: 5, b:2} as Required<MyType>}

Defaults.myDefault.c
```

yields

```js
(property) c: number
```

Comment: Thank's a lot for you explanation, I think this answers most of my questions. But do you know why typing `as Required<MyType>` which comes down to `Required<T> = { [P in keyof T]-?: T[P]; }` which is supposed to make all properties in T required does not make it more specific?

Comment: Please, consider my updated answer.

Answer (score 2):

David Scholz answer seems right, but I think you may prefer to not use the `as` operator in this case. If you fully type the variable `Defaults`, TypeScript will complain `c` is not specified as expected:

```js
type MyType = {a: number, b: number, c: number}
type DefaultsType = {myDefault: MyType};

const defaults: DefaultsType = {myDefault: {a: 5, b: 6}}
```